# Should I encrypt a CSV file in the Assets folder for a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) application?

Tags: c#, uwp

I will soon release a UWP application that is predicated on a CSV file that is stored in the Assets folder.  I do not want the users to have access to that file, as the information in it is the valuable part of my application.

Should I encrypt that file?

I have reviewed lots of documentation, but I can't figure out if that file has any inherent protection by virtue of being in the Assets folder, as opposed to the AppData folder.

Comment: Not necessary if you set the privileges properly.  Each user should have their own login.  You can run the UWP with admin privilege so app can write file and then users cannot read.

Comment: As your application has to decrypt it, the decryption key has to be on the system, too. So encypting the file might discourage most users, but will not withstand any serious attack. It would be useful if you define the required level of protection clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encrypt it. Once something is on a users computer they can work around most security measures, so they would be able to find the file and read it.

Comment: They would also be able to find the decryption key inside the application, so this doesn't really work against a determined user.